# Sorting a Queue of Structs

Tags: c++, sorting, queue

I currently have a queue that holds a user specified number of structs called **Process**.  Process is made up of a pid, burst, and arrival.  I would like to sort the queue by arrival, but I don't have the faintest idea of where to begin.  Here is some pseudocode to help illustrate what I'm trying to say:

```
struct Process{
    int pid;
    int burst;
    int arrival;
};

void function(int numProcesses){
    queue<Process> readyQueue;

    // The following loop is a shortened version of my code
    for(int i=0; i<numProcesses;i++){
        readyQueue.push(aProcess);
    }

    // This is where I need help!
    // sort(readyQueue);
}
```

I'd be appreciative of anyone who could point me in right direction on how to do this, or if it is even possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can sort using the standard library `std::sort` from the '' header. You can either provide a comparator or define an less operators.

```
struct Process{
    int pid;
    int burst;
    int arrival;
};

    bool operator<(const Process& a, const Process& b) {
          return a.arrival < b.arrival;
    }

    void function(int numProcesses){
        std::dequeue<Process> readyQueue;

        // The following loop is a shortened version of my code
        for(int i=0; i<numProcesses;i++){
             readyQueue.push_back(aProcess);
         }
        std::sort(readyQueue.begin(), readyQueue.end());       
    }
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: He wants process sorted by arrival

Answer (score 3):

Mostly you need to define `operator<` for your class:

```
struct Process{
    int pid;
    int burst;
    int arrival;

    bool operator<(Process const &other) { return arrival < other.arrival; }
};
```

Once you've done that, `std::sort` will work fine:

```
std::sort(std::begin(readyQueue), std::end(readyQueue));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for!  I'm very new to anything other than standard arrays.  Could you possibly explain how I would call sort?  Please and thank you VERY much.

Comment: @Rick_Sch: I've included a sample call to `std::sort`. Minor point: depending on the age of compiler you're using, you may need to use `readyQueue.begin()` instead of `std::begin(readyQueue)` (and likewise for `end`).

Comment: One last thing (I hope):  I get this error when I try to do that readyQueue.begin() method: `error: ‘class std::queue<Process, std::deque<Process, std::allocator<Process> > >’ has no member named ‘begin’`  BUT I also get this error if I try the begin(readyQueue) method: `‘begin’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: You cannot traverse a queue. You can push and pop, but no iteration through a queue.

Comment: Sorry -- hadn't noticed that you were using an actual queue. Easiest to just use an `std::deque` instead. You may not care about inserting and deleting at both ends, but do care about its giving random access to the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::priority_queue` instead...  Otherwise you'll have to sort the queue every time you push something onto it.

Note that you still need to define `operator<`

Comment: I had thought of doing that, but this queue will only ever be added to once, so a priority queue didn't seem necessary.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759112/whats-faster-inserting-into-a-priority-queue-or-sorting-retrospectively) for a debate on the merits of these solutions speed wise.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement a calendar queue. Don't use the `queue` data structure for that but a `set`:

```
struct Process{
    int pid;
    int burst;
    int arrival;
    bool operator<(Process const& other) const {
      if (arrival == other.arrival) {
        if (pid == other.pid)
          return this < &other;
        return pid < other.pid;
      }
      return arrival < other.arrival;
    }
};

void func() {
  std::set<Process> myQueue;
}
```

There is no need to explicitly sort, the set will keep the contents sorted at all times and you can always remove the first by `erase`ing the `begin()` iterator.