# sorting queue of strings

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have a program with a queue of strings. The requirements changed and now the output must be in alphabetical order. I am trying to sort the queue but am getting the error "no matching function call to `'begin(std::queue<std::cxx11__basic::string<char>>&)'` and `'end(std::queue<std::cxx11__basic::string<char>>&)'`

```
queue<std::string> lines = doWork();
std::sort(std::begin(lines), std::end(lines));
```

What's the best way to sort it? Would it be better to change from a queue to a vector or some other structure? The thing is the only operations needed is to add to end and remove from end.

Also I'm using Netbeans and it only displays the compile error messages when I hover over the red x so how can I copy and paste the message?

EDIT: I now understand queues can't be sorted. So what then is the best data structure to use? It only needs to be added to from one end, sorted and red linearally (from start to end)?

Comment: A queue is a FIFO, you can't sort it.

Comment: 'Sorting queue' is a contradiction in terms. You can have a 'priority queue' which orders *itself*, but sorting a queue that already exists violates both concepts.

Comment: @EJP this question made it seem possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280726/sorting-a-queue-of-structs

Comment: @northerner see the comments on the accepted answer by Jerry: `You cannot traverse a queue ... - user515430`, `Sorry -- hadn't noticed that you were using an actual queue. Easiest to just use an std::deque instead ... - Jerry Coffin`. It's unfortunate that the answer itself has not been updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) is `std::queue`. It has no `begin` and `end` - that would defeat the purpose of the wrapper. Choose `std::vector` instead or use [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Answer (score 0):

[`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) has no `begin` and `end`, the order is always FIFO by definition.

Choose [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead, it can be sorted and, unlike [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), has `pop_front` and offers better performance for FIFO operations.

Comment: Is there a place to refer to compare the performance of operations on different data structures? I'm looking for something [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Tradeoffs). For example when you say dequeue is faster than vector for FIFO operations, do you speak from experience or is this specified in documentation somewhere?