# When I use custom sort with std::vector, Why use const reference?

Tags: c++, sorting, reference, constants, std

A.

```
bool cmp (const int &a, const int & b) {
     return a < b;
}
```

B.

```
bool cmp (int a, int b) {  
     return a < b; 
}
```

What is different A and B ?

```
vector<int> vec;
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);
```

When I use A and B at cmp, Output is same result.

Comment: I feel decently confident that you can't sort a `std::queue`. Also, do you know what a reference to const means?

Comment: @sweenish It seems that you actually can sort `std::queue` as pointed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280726/sorting-a-queue-of-structs

Comment: To be flippant, the difference between A and B is that A takes its parameters as reference to const while B does not. The better question is: what is a reference to const? That's a two part answer since you need to know what a reference is, and what const is. A reference is the *original* variable, and not a copy (what happens in B). `const` means it can't [easily] be changed. Why we do it is also a two part answer. We don't need to modify the parameters to compare them, so we ensure we can't with const. We pass a reference in case the objects being compared are "heavy" with regards to copying

Comment: @Fryz `std::queue` does not provide iterators. Other answers are using a `std::deque` instead. Most of those answers are bogus or make a change to the question to provide sorting.

Comment: Oh... My mistake... not Queue But Vector.. and I know what is the const and reference. but Both A and B is normally operated in case sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp)

Comment: If you know what const is, and you know what references are, you should have been able to arrive at the answer yourself. This is one of those things that I feel is self-explanatory when you know the parts. And we end up with a very good example of why knowing the proper terms is important.

Comment: @sweenish I think the question arised because the OP tried both codes and, to their surprise, they both work.