# C++ struct sorting performance

Tags: c++

I have to read from the file many (more than 10.000) elements and sort them in the following order: 
{first biggest c1, first biggest c2, first biggest c3, second biggest c1, second biggest c2, first second c3, etc...} and later read them in the sequence order.

```
struct element{
  long c1;
  int c2;
  short c3;
} ;
```

What kind of collection should I use to get best performance?

Of course it is possible to have 3 separate collections and iterate parallel on each one.

On the example, I have the following elements

```
element1 {c1=10, c2=50, c3=90}
element2 {c1=100, c2=10, c3=30}
element3 {c1=5, c2=70, c3=93}
element4 {c1=77, c2=90, c3=0}
element5 {c1=88, c2=30, c3=40}
element6 {c1=99, c2=91, c3=70}
```

I want to have them sorted like this:
element2, element6, element3, element5, element4, element1

```
element2 has the first biggest c1(100),
element6 has the first biggest c2(91),
element3 has the first biggest c3(97),
element5 has the second biggest c1(88),
element4 has the second biggest c2(90),
element1 has the second biggest c3(90),
```

Comment: It depends on when you want to meassure the performance? do you need high performance on insertion, or extraction?

Comment: You might find the answers to this SO question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759112/whats-faster-inserting-into-a-priority-queue-or-sorting-retrospectively

Comment: I need to read whole file once, and pass the elements to the other algorithm.

Comment: Please watch on the example

Answer (score 1):

"What kind of collection should I use to get best performance?" - a `std::vector<element>` is a good fit for storing the elements.

To sort, you've a rather unusual ordering requirement.  I can't think of an efficient way to directly sort the elements into the desired order, so I suggest you initially create three indices - one for each element, then you can iterate through all of them concurrently, taking turns at selecting the next element from each of the three indices, but skipping over any already-selected elements while doing so.

```
std::vector<element> v;
element e;
std::vector<std::pair<decltype(e.c1), size_t>> byc1;
std::vector<std::pair<decltype(e.c2), size_t>> byc2;
std::vector<std::pair<decltype(e.c3), size_t>> byc3;
while (input_file >> e.c1 >> e.c2 >> e.c3)
{
    byc1.emplace_back(e.c1, v.size());
    byc2.emplace_back(e.c2, v.size());
    byc3.emplace_back(e.c3, v.size());
    v.push_back(e);
}
std::sort(byc1.begin(), byc1.end());
std::sort(byc2.begin(), byc2.end());
std::sort(byc3.begin(), byc3.end());
std::vector<bool> already_selected(v.size());
std::vector<size_t> index;
auto in_byc1 = byc1.rbegin();
auto in_byc2 = byc2.rbegin();
auto in_byc3 = byc3.rbegin();
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
    while (already_selected[in_byc1->first])
        ++in_byc1;
    index.push_back(in_byc1->second);
    already_selected[in_byc1->first] = true;

    while (already_selected[in_byc2->first])
        ++in_byc2;
    index.push_back(in_byc2->second);
    already_selected[in_byc2->first] = true;

    while (already_selected[in_byc3->first])
        ++in_byc3;
    index.push_back(in_byc3->second);
    already_selected[in_byc3->first] = true;
}
```

That should leave `index` with the desired order of elements (e.g. in your example, index should contain the numbers 2, 6, 3, 5, 4 and 1): you can then use the values from index to loop up the actual `element` values in `v`.  If you've reason to, you can then use the index to actually sort the data, or a copy of it... left as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: How should I write element comparison function for my problem?

Comment: You should overload `operator<` - lots of existing questions explain how.

Comment: Please watch on the example

Comment: @John: some sample code - untested - edited into the question.

Comment: Tony thanks for the answer, but there are lot of collections and iterations in this implementation.I will try to use one collection(list) and implement my own insert method for this struct. Bad thing here is that, I should swap many elements after each insert.

Comment: @John: good luck with that - let us know how you get on - you can post an answer yourself if you get it working.